# is there any javascript lib to convert HTML to evernote's ENML?

Tags: javascript, evernote

I'm surprised why don't evernote provide an official version of ENML convert tool.

even a ENML online validation will be fine to developers, not only a simple dtd.

so I'm search for a js lib converter for ENML.

had try to use https://code.google.com/p/jquery-clean/ , but got trouble with `<pre> / <code>` tag, it seems got some bug.

Comment: found HtmlSerializer.js at evernote's chrome extensions source, is there any doc for it?

Answer (score 1):

This library works well for me https://github.com/wanasit/enml-js

Answer (score 1):

I wrote [enml2thml](https://github.com/flotemaha/node-html2enml) after I found no library fully supporting what I needed. See if it works for you.